# How to fix "undefined method" error in destroy function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, erb

I am creating a page where a logged in user can view a list of their upcoming reservations and cancel a reservation if need be.

I've tried this as the destroy function:

```
def destroy
    @trip = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    @trip.destroy

    flash[:alert] = "This booking has been cancelled."
    redirect_to your_trips_path 
  end  # destroy/ cancel a booking
```

which produces the following error

```
undefined method `space_reservation' for #<#<Class:0x00007f8198a191d8>:0x00007f8195341160>
Did you mean?  space_reservations_url
```

Here is the relevant code in the controller.rb

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_reservation, only: [:approve, :decline, :destroy]

...

 def your_trips
    @today = DateTime.now
    @trips = current_user.reservations.order(start_date: :desc)
  end

 def destroy
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    @reservation.destroy

    flash[:alert] = "This booking has been cancelled."
    redirect_to your_trips_path 
  end  # destroy/ cancel a booking
```

Routes.rb

```
 resources :spaces, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      get 'listing'
      delete :delete_image_attachment
      get 'preload'
      get 'preview'
      get 'get_dates'
      get 'get_times'
      put :deactivate
      put :activate
      get 'browse_spaces'
    end
      resources :reservations, only: [:create]
      resources :calendars
  end

  resources :reservations, only: [:approve, :decline, :destroy] do
    member do
      post '/approve' => "reservations#approve"
      post '/decline' => "reservations#decline"
      delete 'destroy'
    end
  end
```

View

```
<div class="panel-body">

        <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
...          
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right trips-index">
              <% if trip.start_date && trip.end_date > @today %>
              <%= link_to 'Cancel', 
                          space_reservation(trip), 
                          method: :delete, 
                          class:"btn btn-danger",
                          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> 
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

I would like for the reservation to be deleted when the cancel button is clicked and to no longer appear in the list of reservations. Does anyone spot what I did wrong in the function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that the `space_reservation` method is undefined.

In your view, you called that undefined method here:

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', 
  space_reservation(trip), 
  method: :delete, 
  class:"btn btn-danger",
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> 
<% end %>
```

Assuming everything else works, if you either create the `space_reservation` method or find another way to resolve the issue, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it by changing space_reservation(trip) to reservation_path(trip). Now it works as expected.